# Registry exist not working

Tags: c#, registry

I have a strange situation, 
I would like to use an ini file to list all registry that my program will check if they exist, for example:

[image]

I recover correctly my information and I send the path to another method for check if he exist:

[image]

The message box shows: `"Registry Key does not exist"`, but when I put the path manually like below, then it works as expected:

[image]

Do you know why ?

Comment: Put your actual code directly in the question, we don't like images of code

Comment: try run as admin

Comment: Your output of the first message box is wrong instead of @"System\" it should be only System\

Comment: Well the two strings are not the same. The one read from the text file is `@"\System"` and the one you supply manually is `System\\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to write code in your ini file, rather than just the key. Your ini file should be something like:

```
[RegistryExist]
System\=
```

Then it will match your hard-coded attempt.

Note that I am assuming you are splitting on that `=` in which case it won't be included in the check.

---

Stepping through your code with the debugger and checking the exact value of `reg` should have been enough to identify this problem on your own. I suggest getting to terms with debugging.